# onClickListener problems

Tags: android, eclipse, button

So im trying to make a simple image button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button_image" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc/>
```

xml:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected void onCreate1 (Bundle savedInstaceState){
    Bundle savedInstanceState;
    super .onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1  = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);

            View.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener () {
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked it. Genius.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

but it keeps popping up the error: `"The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new onClickListener(){})"`

I imported `android.view.View.OnClickLIstener;`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: button1.setOnClickListener(...

Comment: also cast to ImageButton itself

Comment: @dymmeh the same error comes up :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do this:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Use **button1** and check **OnClickListener** casing.

Comment: still the same error "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new onClickListener(){})"

Comment: Did you save your Java file before compiling? The error message is showing "onClickListener" whereas your code is supposedly now using "OnClickListener".

Answer (score 1):

to use onClickListener use this code

```
        Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
    bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is that an `onclick` handler implements the interface `View.OnClickListener`. You need to create a class that implements the interface because you need to add your code that get’s executed. .

your `onClickListener` should be be used as follows:

```
 Button button1  = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);

        View.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener () {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked it. Genius.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

OR

By creating class Inline as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Inform the user the button has been clicked
   }
```

});